# Annoying beep when I hit enter in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to have some stuff happen when a user presses enter in a textbox, and it works, but it makes a very annoying DING windows error sound when I do. I've looked up my problem, and apparently adding `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` before the stuff, and `e.Handled = true;` after the stuff, but my program still makes the sound. This is the code I'm using:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // A bunch of stuff goes here that I want to 
        // happen when the user hits enter               
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? This is what the other people said you have to do, but it's not working for me for some reason...

Thanks!

Comment: Up is good for the mouse. Down is good for the keyboard.  Ding! if you get it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You need to handle `KeyDown`, not `KeyUp`, in order to suppress the `KeyPress` event.  The [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation explains why, as it lists the order of events as:

- KeyDown
- KeyPress
- KeyUp

At the point you're setting `e.SupressKeyPress`, the `KeyPress` event has already occurred.

Comment: Awe man, I've got about 50 instances of this to change to keydown now xD Thanks though, now I know whats wrong!

Comment: @Nathan: Global replace, or an editor like sublime text might help :)

Comment: Can a global replace actually change which event does something? I made my events by double clicking "Keyup" in the event menu of a control and typing in the method that was created.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, as long as you include the .designer.cs files, since that's where the hooks occur in code.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this !

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    if (e.KeyCode == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        // A bunch of stuff goes here that I want to 
        // happen when the user hits enter         
        e.Handled = true;      
    }  
}
```

Comment: You should change your answer to make it more than just a code snippet. Try explaining what the snippet is doing and linking to some relevant resources.

Answer (score 0):

What you did was not wrong just put (e.supperkeypress = ture) inside if statement.

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        // A bunch of stuff goes here that I want to 
        // happen when the user hits enter               
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```